# Redirect traffic from Azure Public LB to VMs without public IP address

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

I have a website hosted on 2 Azure VMs (Web Server: IIS, OS: Win 2016, Port: 80)
Both the VMs are a part of the same availability set and subnet.
And these VMs are added to the backend pool of the Azure Public LB.
Inbound NAT rules of the Azure LB are configured to redirect traffic received on Port:80 to the target VMs. NSG of the VM's subnet already have default rule "AllowAzureLoadBalancerInBound"

1. Is this one of the right configurations to access websites hosted on Azure VMs from outside without adding a public IP for the VMs?
2. What is the "None" setting for the target virtual machine configuration meant?

I am able to access the sites hosted on both the VMs from a different VM within the same VNet using private IPs of VMs. But I am not able to access the sites using the public IP address of the Azure LB.
Error: "The site can't be reached"

**Current Configuration:**

- 2 VMs (10.2.0.4 and 10.2.0.5)
- Load balancer has a public IP.
- One front end IP configuration is added with the LB's public IP. This frontend configuration is used within Inbound NAT rule.
- Inboud NAT Rules:
  Front end ip address: Public IP of load balancer, Service: HTTP, Protocol: UDP, Port: 80, Target Virtual Machine: None, Port Mapping: Default
- Backend pools: Private IPs of both VMs are added to backend pool
- Created a health probe with Port:80
- Load balancing rules: None

Can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: Could you please share you LB configuration and Backend status?

Comment: @AndriyBilous Updated the question with more details. "Resource Status" for both the VMs in the backend pool shows as "Running".

Comment: You need to create Load balancing rule. See example http://www.msserverpro.com/deploy-and-configure-vm-scale-sets-vmss-in-the-azure-portal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use LB rules themselves and not NAT rules. LB rules were not working initially when I tried to redirect traffic from the public internet to VMs with the only private IP address. Hence I started trying with NAT rules. This was the wrong choice. Thank you @Andriy. The root cause was identified after troubleshooting connectivity with a network watcher. The message was "Security rule DenyAllInBound". Requests from our machines reach the Azure VMs using a different IP and not with the IP of our ISP due to the Security tools installed on our system. Hence I added an inbound rule for this IP to make it work.